# How to install Superset as a cluster in three Linux machines

Tags: apache-superset, supertest

Hi we are using Superset for duckDB, works fine, but superset will not allow to connect duckDB file from another machine, we need to connect duckDB file from the local path and process duckDB in local machine, where superset is installed.
So to distribute the load, we are planning to install Superset as a cluster in three machine, but don't know how to install superset in a distributed mode in three machine.

If anyone have installed superset as cluster or distributed mode, in more than one machine, please help me with instruction or any doc available to follow.

Thanks in  advance.

Comment: what about kubernetes ? does it work for your requierement ?

Comment: No we are not using kubernetes

Answer (score 0):

Per Superset official documentation you can install superset on Kubernetes.
Since you are asking for available documentation here are some useful links.

1. [Kubernetes installation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/)
2. [Installing superset on Kubernetes](https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/running-on-kubernetes/)

Comment: Thanks for the docs, I will refer, try to use it without kuburnetes.

Comment: it will not be possible. kubernetes is intended to "clusterize" an application